# Menu options missing in node form

Tags: 8, forms, navigation

In Drupal 8, despite the fact that there is a menu set for the content type, menu options are not showing in the node form.

I have disabled some menu modules in case they were interfering, but with no result.

[image: Form without menu settings]

What else can I check?

Comment: Have you checked permissions and cleared caches?

Comment: Yes, and it’s happening with the administrator user.

Comment: How about if you switch the administration theme? That would help narrow down if it's a theme hook causing the issue.

Comment: I thought that too, I changed it with no results.

Comment: Maybe theres something corrupt in the content type/node settings. What if you try creating a new content type to test?

Comment: Ok, I’ll try that.

Comment: It didn't work. I've created a new content type, set a menu for it, but menu settings are not showing either here.

Comment: Have you used drush to check and see if there are any outstanding database updates or entity updates with the existing codebase?

Comment: No updates pending :'-(

Comment: Are you running latest releases?

Comment: Yes, everything is updated, core and modules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it. Silly me, it was the module [Menu link (field)](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_link), it actually says in the project page `The "Menu settings" tab is however removed from the node form and replaced by an field widget`. Argh, so much time looking for the reason, I didn't see that one when I uninstalled the ones that were interfering.